# jquery loop through multiple elements, and change multiple elements at the same time?

Tags: jquery, loops

I have the following html example

```
<div id="main"><input type="hidden" name="bilbo" value="0"><a id="baggins" href="somewhere.com"></div>
<div id="main"><a id="baggins" href="somewhere-else.com"></div>
<div id="main"><a id="baggins" href="somewhere-elseagain.com"></div>
```

What I need to do is loop through each div with the id of main and find if the input type hidden exists.

Then I need to change the href of that link in the same div as the input hidden, each time, there will be more than one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a sidenote, an id has to be unique, use classes instead.

Comment: the html is a rendered rss feed...unfortunately

Comment: since this is a rendered rss feed, it is being transformed with xslt, so each of the divs is built in a for-each...

Comment: since they are built in a for each the if($('input[name=bilbo]')) doesn't work, because it only reads the first one and not the subsequent divs after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have no control over the HTML, forget the ID then.

`$('div:has(input[type=hidden]) a')`

This means, give me all hyperlinks that are nested inside a `div` element that must have a hidden input nested in the DIVs.

You should have roughly the following

```
$('div:has(input[type=hidden]) a').each(function (i, link) {
    $(link).attr('href', 'whatever.bla');
});
```

---

In case you are fetching the rss feed html into a string, then you can probably do this:

```
// assuming you fetched the rss feed as a string or responseText
var htmlString = '<div id="main"><input type="hidden" name="bilbo" value="0"><a id="baggins" href="somewhere.com"></div><div id="main"><a id="baggins" href="somewhere-else.com"></div><div id="main"><a id="baggins" href="somewhere-elseagain.com"></div>';

var $feeds = $(htmlString);

$feeds.find('div:has(input[type=hidden]) a').each(function (i, link) {
    $(link).attr('href', 'whatever.bla');
});
```

Comment: What if I wanted to loop through and see which divs did NOT contain the input hiddens?

Comment: nevermind, I found that one. $('div:not(:has(input[type=hidden])) a')

Comment: `$('div:not(:has(input[type=hidden])) a')`

Comment: Right, you gotta love jQuery just for this

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use classes and not repeating IDs

```
$(".main").each(function() {
    var isHidden = $(this).children("input[type='hidden']").length > 0;
    if (isHidden) {
        $(this).children("input[type='hidden']").nextAll("a").each(function() {
            //Change the href now
            $(this).attr("href", "newlink");
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Rc9X/